# Writing out BMP files with DataBuffer.TYPE_FLOAT or DataBuffer.TYPE_DOUBLE in java

Tags: java, image, writer

I had a problem working with the image classes in java.

I am creating a buffered image with DataBuffer.TYPE_DOUBLE. This all works fine in memory (I think). But the problem starts when I try to write it using ImageIO.write.

Initially I was getting no exception at all and instead was only getting an empty output file for my troubles..

After a bit of poking around in the code, i found out that the bmp writer doesnt support writing type_double type of files.

```
From: BMPImageWriterSpi.canEncodeImage:
        if (dataType < DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE || dataType > DataBuffer.TYPE_INT)
        return false;
```

So my question is, does anyone have a way of writing out those kind of images to disk? any documentation or tutorial, or link would be helpful.

Thanks,
Basil Dsouza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the BMP format doesn't use any floating-point representations, at a high level it doesn't quite make sense to use floating-point data to represent an image that you will write as a BMP. Do you really need to do that? Why not ints?

The [javadoc for `DataBuffer.TYPE_DOUBLE`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/DataBuffer.html#TYPE_DOUBLE) suggests it's not currently intended for use.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I went through so much sun source code, but didnt read the published java docs :)

Though the rest of my code works with double. As in, i can set and read values through the raster when i use TYPE_DOUBLE, and i can normalize and denormalize them via other color models well. But it makes sense.

What i really was trying to do was implement a steganography application. (In a somewhat misguided way). So its back to the drawing board, and perhaps i should read that paper on steganography staring at me from the shelf :)